# Specify negative path match for servlet mapping

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Is there a way to specify negative mappings in `web.xml`? For example, I want to set a filter for ALL requests EXCEPT those matching '`/public/*`'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You'd have to do the URL pattern matching yourself inside the `doFilter()` method. Map the filter on `/*` and do the following job:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

if (req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/public/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

// ...
```

or when there's actually a context path:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

if (req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + "/public/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

// ...
```