# Clicking on commandlink gives Error: 'mojarra' is undefined

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I am using JSF 2.2 and having mojarra implementation. I am getting the below javascript error whenever I click on a command link and the request is not submitted into the server. When the command button is clicked, it seems ok. The error is Error: 'mojarra' is undefined
In the attached view source, it is showing in the link number 32 at mojarra.jsfcljs(..

Not sure what is causing the problem. I have an authentication filter configured in web.xml with url pattern as /faces/* 
Also, I tried this url (/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces) in the browser and it worked fine and it took me to the login page(as the user is not signed in.)
Also, somewhere in the web app there is a reference to primefaces as well.
Any inputs will be of great help.
Thanks.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-sam" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/core.js;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/components.css;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/components.js;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale='en';}</script>

        <link href="/MyApp/resources/css/cssfile1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/MyApp/resources/css/cssfile2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <title>MyApp: Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/resources/scripts/scriptfile1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/resources/scripts/scriptfile2.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /></head><body onload=""><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div id="header_background">

        <div id="header">
        <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/Mylogo.gif"  />

        </div>
<form id="nsform" name="nsform" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="nsform" value="nsform" />


            <div id="nssys" >
                <ul>
                    <li id="nvgreeting">welcome XYZ
                    </li>

                    <li id="nvcontact_us"><a id="nsform:nvlink_contact_us" name="nsform:nvlink_contact_us" href="/MyApp/faces/contact_us.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768">contact us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nvhelp">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces"></script>
<a id="nsform:nvlink_help" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nsform'),{'nsform:nvlink_help':'nsform:nvlink_help'},'');return false">help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
        <span class="hidden">Step 1 Bar: </span>
<form id="nv_form" name="nv_form" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="nv_form" value="nv_form" />

            <div id="nav_bar"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt24':'nv_form:j_idt24'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 1" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt26':'nv_form:j_idt26'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 2" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt28':'nv_form:j_idt28'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 3" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt30':'nv_form:j_idt30'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 4" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt32':'nv_form:j_idt32'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 5" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt34':'nv_form:j_idt34'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 6" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('nv_form'),{'nv_form:j_idt36':'nv_form:j_idt36'},'');return false" >
                <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/tn.png" alt="Link 7" /></a>

            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:1" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

    </div>
</html>

        <div id="header_sub">

         <div class="content_margins">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<form id="bccform" name="bccform" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="bdform" value="bdform" />

    <div class="horznavigation" id="bccs">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('bdform'),{'j_idt45:0:j_idt47':'j_idt45:0:j_idt47','actionMethod':'setPersons','actionClass':'pack.alerts.NBean','key':'managedBeanBacking'},'');return false">Filter</a> <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/img3.gif;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768"  />


          </li>
          <li> <h1>Filters</h1>


          </li>



      </ul>

    </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:2" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
  <!-- End Breadcrumb -->
</html>
      <!--Breadcrumb End-->
<form id="billNavBarForm" name="billNavBarForm" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" style="margin-bottom: 0">
<input type="hidden" name="billNavBarForm" value="billNavBarForm" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <div id="bill_nav_tabs"><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('billNavBarForm'),{'billNavBarForm:j_idt59':'billNavBarForm:j_idt59'},'');return false" class="basic_selected">
            <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/transparent-wide.png"  title="Basic Search" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('billNavBarForm'),{'billNavBarForm:j_idt61':'billNavBarForm:j_idt61'},'');return false" class="textSearch_selected_not">
            <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/transparent-wide.png"  title="Text Search" /></a><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('billNavBarForm'),{'billNavBarForm:j_idt63':'billNavBarForm:j_idt63'},'');return false" class="advanced_selected_not">
            <img src="/MyApp/resources/images/transparent-wide.png"  title="Advanced Search" /></a><img src="/MyApp/resources/images/right-end.png" />
    </div>

</html><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:3" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
      <div id="billtext" class="tab_content">

        <div class="tab_content_sub_non_text"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt70"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-sam" /><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale='en';}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/resources/scripts/scriptfile1.js"></script>
        <style>
            .holder {
                width: 100%;
                display: none;
            }

            .popup {
                border-radius: 7px;
                background: #4b4a43;
                padding: 6px;
                position : absolute;
                width: 41%;
                height: 42em;
                top: 13%;
                left: 33%;
                right: 32%;
            }
        </style></head>
    <div id="bill_form">
<form id="filter_form" name="filter_form" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="filter_form" value="filter_form" />


            <div id="term_criteria">
                <h2>
                    Filter Condition
                </h2><span class="form_input"><label for="filter_form:measure_num">Input:</label><input id="filter_form:measure_num" type="text" name="filter_form:measure_num" maxlength="8" onkeypress="handleSubmitAction(event, this.name, this.form, true ? 'attrSearch' : 'createReport')" /></span><span class="form_input"><label for="filter_form:house">DropDown:</label>

                <select id="filter_form:Option" name="filter_form:Option" size="1" onchange="document.getElementById('filter_form:hiddenHouseBtn').click();"> <option value="Both" selected="selected">All</option>
 <option value="none">None</option>
 <option value="some">Some</option>
</select>

<input id="filter_form:hiddenHouseBtn" type="submit" name="filter_form:hiddenHouseBtn" value="" style="display: none;" /></span>
<span class="form_input">
<input id="filter_form:locationtype" type="hidden" name="filter_form:locationtype" />
<label for="filter_form:session_year">Date of Birth:</label>

<input id="filter_form:hiddenSessionYrBtn" type="submit" name="filter_form:hiddenSessionYrBtn" value="" style="display: none;" /></span>
<span class="form_input"><label for="filter_form:stype">S Type:</label><select id="filter_form:stype" name="filter_form:stype" size="1" style="font-family: Arial, 'Courier New', 'Times New Roman'"> <option value="S1">S1</option>
 <option value="All" selected="selected">All</option>
</select>
</span>


            </div>



            <div style="clear:both;"></div>


            <div id="btn"><input id="filter_form:btnsubm" type="submit" name="filter_form:btnsubm" value="Execute"  />  <input type="submit" name="filter_form:j_idt194" value="Clear" class="buttons" />

            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:4" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
<form id="hidden" name="hidden" method="post" action="/MyApp/faces/Step1/myPage1.xhtml;jsessionid=X3r_Oc5yvD29rewNgrCvvGPD9mSLgrEI9Wvvwvi-VaJCBwXqO_tX!1107612768" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="popup">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="hidden" />
<input id="hidden:ltype" type="hidden" name="hidden:ltype" /><input id="hidden:sessionyr" type="hidden" name="hidden:doy" value="2000" /><a id="hidden:go" href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('hidden'),{'hidden:go':'hidden:go'},'');return false"></a><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:5" value="234044955079246741:5229577762117219928" autocomplete="off" />
</form>





    </div>

</html>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        </div></body>


</html>
```

Comment: Debug network traffic... any other return codes than 200 or 304?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708706/using-servlet-filter-on-all-the-pages-except-the-index

Comment: You should exclude the resources from the filter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and altered the filter for the fix.